# How to insert array items after a post request in MySQL using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express, backend

am new web development, am having difficulties to insert items which are stored in an array in my nodejs app. I have an array which collects information of my checkout page. I want to insert all the values in the database, but the problem is when the array has more items from the checkout page is failing to insert as the other columns are not recognised in the databases.

Below is the code that I want to use to insert the data in the database. I want to insert everything which is in the prodDetails into the databases, again it could more data or less data

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '',
    user     : '',
    password : '',
    database : ''
});
//router to post
app.post('/create', function(req, res, next) {
    // store all the products in product details
    const prodDetails=req.body;
    console.log(prodDetails);
    //var txt = JSON.stringify(prodDetails);
    // insert product data into all products table
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO allproducts SET ?';
    db.query(sql, prodDetails,function (err, data) { 
        if (err) throw err; //if sql error throw
        console.log(prodDetails);
        console.log("Product added data is inserted in instock table successfully "); 
    });
    res.redirect('/checkout');  //
});
```

Below is the output in my console this how am getting the results from the check out page ejs file that is after its printing the values from ejs by using the above code on line console.log(prodDetails);

```
{ cmd: '_cart',
  upload: '1',
  business: 'seller@deotos.com',
  quantity_1: '1',
  item_name_1: 'Cable 3',
  amount_1: '12.00',
  quantity_2: '1',
  item_name_2: 'iPad white',
  amount_2: '300.00',
  quantity_3: '1',
  item_name_3: 'Cable 1',
  amount_3: '3.00',
  quantity_4: '1',
  item_name_4: 'SD Card 16GB',
  amount_4: '20.00',
  customername: 'Johnson',
  customerphone: '876654',
  customeremail: 'Jaqueleen@gm.org',
  customeraddress: 'London' }
```

and below is my sql table, it has 12 rows, the problem is when a person orders more than 12 items how can I achieve this so that after quantity it should start writing on another row for all items in the prodDetails

```
create table allproducts (
    id INT(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    cmd VARCHAR(255), 
    upload INT(50), 
    business varchar(255),
    quantity_1 INT(50), 
    item_name VARCHAR(255), 
    amount INT(30), 
    customername VARCHAR(255), 
    customerphone VARCHAR(25), 
    customeremail VARCHAR(25), 
    customeraddress VARCHAR(25), 
    date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);

+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+
| id              | int(50)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              |
| cmd             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |
| upload          | int(50)      | YES  |     | NULL              |
| business        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |
| quantity_1      | int(50)      | YES  |     | NULL              |
| item_name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |
| amount          | int(30)      | YES  |     | NULL              |
| customername    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |
| customerphone   | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL              |
| customeremail   | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL              |
| customeraddress | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL              |
| date            | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: your sql must look like this, var sql = 'INSERT INTO allproducts SET prodDetails = ?';  but you didn't tell us the structure of the table

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting up your data across tables and linking them through the use of foreign keys. Repeating customer information in multiple rows for each item violates **second normal form (2NF)**. You can read more about database normalization rules and its importance here:

https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html

In your case, you could organize your data into a `Customer`, `Order`, `Product`, and `Order_Product` table. The pseudo-code for your structure may look something like this:

```
Customer {
   customer_id int PK,
   customer_name varchar,
   customer_email varchar
}

Order {
   order_id int PK,
   customer_id int FK REF Customer,
   order_date timestamp
}

Order_Product {
   order_product_id int PK,
   order_id FK REF Order,
   product_id FK REF Product,
   product_quantity
}

Product {
   product_id int PK,
   product_name varchar,
   product_cost float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to adjust the format of the POST data to look like:

```
   { 
      cmd: '_cart',
      upload: '1',
      business: 'seller@deotos.com',
      items: [
        {
          quantity_1: '1',
          item_name: 'Cable 3',
          amount: '12.00'
        },
        {
          quantity_1: '1',
          item_name: 'iPad white',
          amount: '300.00'
        },
        {
          quantity_1: '1',
          item_name: 'Cable 1',
          amount: '3.00'
        },
        { 
          quantity_1: '1',
          item_name: 'SD Card 16GB',
          amount: '20.00'
        }
      ],
      customername: 'Johnson',
      customerphone: '876654',
      customeremail: 'Jaqueleen@gm.org',
      customeraddress: 'London'
      }
```

The naming of the `quantity_1` seems odd to me, i suggest to change the column name to `quantity`.

You can then loop over items` to insert the orders. This should work to get your current problem solved and get the data into the DB.

Please note that there should be additional steps to refine the DB structure as suggested by @Jakob K

Comment: @Jacob K. Thank you very much I will try the approach